# Is MRI permanent magnet sensitive to temperature?

Tags: magnetic-fields, temperature, medical-physics

My question is related to MRI machines that use a permanent magnet to generate their main magnetic field:

Are all permanent magnets used in such MRI machines sensitive to temperature, meaning does a change in temperature change the magnetic field of the permanent magnet? If so, then do we need to control the room temperature where the MRI machine is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Most MRI systems use superconducting electro magnets rather than permanent magnets for this reason (among others). However, for the MRI systems that do use permanent magnets, one of their major problems is that those magnets are sensitive to changes in temperature.

Although control of the room temperature is important, a bigger problem is that the use of the magnetic field gradient coils produces a hysteresis inside the permanent magnet, and this hysteresis itself is a source of heat that is generated directly inside the permanent magnet.

So even if the room is maintained at exactly the same temperature, the permanent magnets will unavoidably display some thermally-driven field drift in the course of normal operation.